# Why do my components not updating reactively in this vuejs application?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm currently shooting into the dark at the moment. The code below (and dev environment) are nothing to be proud of. I have just now started to learn vuejs using a small project as guinea pig. I am advancing, but I have a problem regarding vuex.

I'm still fooling about, so please disregard some weird code (especially the choice and structure of route/team assignments). That will be refactored later, and shouldn't be related to the issue.

## Quick Problem Description (details follow below)

- I have a vuex store
- One view (the route list) contains a list of `RouteBlock` components. Each `RouteBlock` contains a list of teams which are assigned to *that* route, and a list of teams assigned to *no* route.
- When clicking the "assign" button, a previously unassigned group will become assigned to *one* route, and will **disappear from the "unassigned" list of *each* `RouteBlock`**
- This currently only works when [refreshing the complete state from the server](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/powonline/src/main.js#L195). From what I understand this should not be necessary thanks to `vuex`. I'm trying to find out what I need to change to make this work without a full refresh.

*If you don't want to bother running the code, you can scroll down to the bottom to the "Following the Flow" section.*

## The code / Running Example / Demo

I added a tag to keep a reference to [the code at the time of this writing](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/tree/stackoverflow-2017-06-09)
Here's a link to a snapshot of the code at the time of this writing. The folder `frontend` contains the vuejs code, whereas the `powonline` folder contains the Python backend.

Getting the Python part up and running should be as easy as:

```
git clone https://github.com/exhuma/powonline.git
cd powonline
git checkout stackoverflow-2017-06-09
pyvenv env
./env/bin/pip install -e .
./env/bin/python autoapp.py
```

Everything here in this prototype runs in-memory. There is no persistent storage. If the Python process restarts, the data is reset!

The vuejs part is located in [the frontend folder](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/tree/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/powonline). I've had some issues getting npm set-up and ended up creating two docker containers in [the frontend root](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/tree/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend), with two helper scripts ([1](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/vue) and [2](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/npm)). Those script contain hard-coded folders which certainly must be changed! When building the containers, they should have the names `exhuma/npm` and `exhuma/vue` as appropriate, so they can be run using the helper scripts. It is likely that files created (if any) by one of those containers are owned by "root", which also needs to be fixed via a `chown` (but normally, no files will be created, I think).

With everything in place, and using docker, the frontend should be runnable using:

```
cd powonline/frontend
./npm run dev
```

## Preparing Example Data for Testing

- Access the frontend
- Click on "Teams"
- Add two teams ("Team 1" and "Team 2")
- Click on "Routes"
- Add two routes ("Route 1" and "Route 2")

You then should see something like the following:

---

[image: Team List]

---

[image: Route List]

---

## Following the Flow, and my Thoughts

- A user clicking on "Assign" calls [`assign`](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/powonline/src/components/RouteBlock.vue#L40) which dispatches to the vuex action [`assignTeamToRouteRemote`](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/powonline/src/main.js#L183)
- This triggers an async remote action. Once this returns the new data is committed using the [`assignTeamToRoute`](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/powonline/src/main.js#L194) mutation. **This is what I expect to trigger a reactive update, but which doesn't!**
- I've added a dispatch to action `refreshRemote` because the reactive change above does not happen. I want to remove that (if possible)!
- The view in turn uses [a computed property (`assignedTeams`)](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/powonline/src/components/RouteBlock.vue#L27), which delegates to the *vuex* getter [`assignedTeams`](https://github.com/exhuma/powonline/blob/stackoverflow-2017-06-09/frontend/powonline/src/main.js#L242). I would expect this to update after the previous changes. Is it possible that this is cached (as per [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)?) and that vuejs does not detect the change of the getter as a dependency and hence does not update the cache? I've tried to move it over to a method instead of a property, but then I ran into a weird CORS problem...

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. The problem is probably around how you're performing the `assignTeamToRoute` mutation

Comment: Also, *"I've tried to move it over to a method instead of a property, but then I ran into a weird CORS problem"* makes absolutely no sense

Comment: @Phil I linked to the appropriate parts of the code. I'm not experienced enough with vue yet to pinpoint the exact statements or flows causing the error. I would add the code to the question of I knew which part it was 

Comment: @Phil you mean the sentence phrasing? Or the fact that suddenly out of nowhere CORS errors popped up? What actually happened was that as soon as the property was converted to a method, the backend no longer returned "allow origin" headers. And I agree that this is surprising. I was perplexed as well when I saw that.

Answer (score 0):

With Vuex, it's best to treat the state properties (in mutations) as immutable.

Your `assignTeamToRoute` mutation is potentially adding object properties which is not *reactive* (see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)

Try the following using `Vue.set`...

```
assignTeamToRoute (state, payload) {
  const current = state.route_team_map[payload.routeName] || [];
  Vue.set(state.route_team_map, payload.routeName, current.concat(payload.team.name))
}
```

You'll probably need to do something similar with the mutations that remove teams from routes.